# How do i store tag/child tag values that has been read from multiple XML files into a single CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv, elementtree

I have a dataset that contains multiple XML files and those files have multiple tags and sub/child tags, I am reading all the files using 'xml.etree.ElementTree' `for files in filename: print(files) tree = ET.parse(files) root = tree.getroot()`. There's a parent tag name "Event" However, when I run a loop it reads the value of the last file's parent tag and stores the values in a CSV file based on that last file. How do i fix my code in order to read tag value/parent tag from all the files and store it in a single CSV file. The code i have written is :

```
mypath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/CTIDataset'
csvfile = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/TESTCTI.csv",'w',encoding='utf-8')
csvfile_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
csvfile_writer.writerow(["Event_ID","Date","Info","Category","Comment","Value","Type","Att_ID"])
for files in filename:
  with open(files,"rb"):
    tree = ET.parse(files)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for tag in root.findall("Event"):
       Ev_ID = getattr(tag.find("id"),'text',None)
       Date = getattr(tag.find("date"),'text',None)
       info = getattr(tag.find("info"),'text',None)
       for attribute in tag:
         if(attribute):
           category = getattr(attribute.find("category"),'text',None)
           comment = getattr(attribute.find("comment"),'text',None)
           value = getattr(attribute.find("value"),'text',None)
           type_ = getattr(attribute.find("type"),'text',None)
           att_id = getattr(attribute.find("id"),'text',None)
       csv_line = [Ev_ID,Date,info,category,comment,value,type_,att_id]
       csvfile_writer.writerow(csv_line)
```

Comment: maybe first get data from all files and later write all to `csv`.

Comment: do you open CSV file only once? If you open it many times then you have to use `append mode`

Comment: I am reading all the files and i doubt it has to do with opening the CSV file only once, as i don't get all values of a tag let say "id" as mentioned in code, even after using print. It means that the for loop is only picking up values of last file.

Comment: your problem suggest that you open again CSV and write new data but using `write mode` which removes previous content- and it needs `append mode` to append new data to existing file. If you open csv only once then it should write all values without problem.

Comment: better create minimal working code so we could see how you use files and where you print values. Current code seems OK and I don't see what can make problem - so problem has to be in different place

Comment: I have edited it a bit, maybe you can check it now.

Comment: The problem of picking up data of tags of all files has been resolved but when I write that data on CSV file the child tags under the for loop: `for attribute in tag:` still don't get written in csv file.

Comment: so you have something wrong with writing data - maybe you should simply `csvfile.close()` file because system may keep data in buffer and it may not save it when you don't close it.

Comment: I think I understand what can be the problem - you have wrong indentation - you have to write inside `if attribute:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand problem but you have wrong indentations.

You have to write inside `if`

```
for attribute in tag:
    if attribute:
        category = getattr(attribute.find("category"),'text',None)
        comment = getattr(attribute.find("comment"),'text',None)
        value = getattr(attribute.find("value"),'text',None)
        type_ = getattr(attribute.find("type"),'text',None)
        att_id = getattr(attribute.find("id"),'text',None)
        # --- inside `if` ---
        csv_line = [Ev_ID,Date,info,category,comment,value,type_,att_id]
        csvfile_writer.writerow(csv_line)
```